# Compute volume of region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to compute the volume of a region bounded by the planes $z=0$, $y=-1$, $y=1$ and the parabolic cylinder $z=1-x^2$.

I really don't know how to tackle this problem. I thought maybe something like $2 \int_{-1}^{1} \! z(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ could be correct, but I don't really now if my reasoning is correct.

My thoughts were $\int_{-1}^{1} \! z(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ gives us the area of the parabolic cylinder and then I have to multiply with the length of the y-interval, so 2. Am I even close to the right answer? And if so, how can I formalize this?

Edit: new thought as a result of a comment.

$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \! z(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y$

I believe this equates to the same thing I wrote initally (yet more formal), but is it correct?

Comment: A hint: volume is a 3-dimensional quantity, so you need to integrate with respect to three dimensions to obtain volume.

Comment: @Pockets, but I don't have an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$ or $z$. How should I go about that?

Comment: The answer's been given, but you got it in your edit: your integrand with respect to the $y$ is just the constant 1.

Comment: Your thinking is correct: the volume of a cylinder is given by $V=Bh$, where $B$ is the area of the base and $h$ is the height, so here $B=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)dx$ and $h=2$.

Answer (score 1):

A visual can help with these problems:

[image: Region of integration]

This region results in the integral $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{1-x^2} dz\,dy\,dx$$